# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

```
buildTypes {
    release {

        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

When I make `proguard` to my app. I get following Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'
```

Comment: put `--stacktrace` and see why it fails

Comment: `gradlew transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease --stacktrace`